# Puente con Pepper 2.9.5.172

Tags: bash

Me gustaría saber si es posible conectar ROS con Pepper Naoqi 2.9.5.172. Y en tal caso como se podría hacer dicha conexión. Me gustaría poder realizar mapeos con Pepper y poder guardarlos con ROS. Anteriormente, ejecuté aplicaciones sobre Pepper que me permitían guardar mapas en archivos .txt, pero son imposibles de interpretar. Sé que en la versión de Naoqi 2.5 era posible realizar este tipo de puentes y descargar mapas en formato .yaml y me gustaría conseguir algo parecido.

Muchas gracias por la información.